# Как максимально быстро прочитать CSV файл и вытащить из него только нужные данные?

Tags: python, csv

Дан большой CSV файл:

```
time,mouse-key
2021-02-08T13:53:57.013,"{}"
2021-02-08T13:53:57.015,"{}"
2021-02-08T13:53:57.020,"{}"
2021-02-08T13:53:57.027,"{'LEFT'}"
2021-02-08T13:53:57.030,"{'LEFT'}"
2021-02-08T13:53:57.034,"{'LEFT'}"
2021-02-08T13:53:57.042,"{'LEFT'}"
2021-02-08T13:53:57.042,"{'LEFT'}"
2021-02-08T13:53:57.046,"{'LEFT'}"
2021-02-08T13:53:57.051,"{'LEFT'}"
2021-02-08T13:53:57.055,"{'LEFT'}"
2021-02-08T13:53:57.059,"{'LEFT'}"
2021-02-08T13:53:57.064,"{'LEFT'}"
2021-02-08T13:53:57.068,"{'LEFT'}"
2021-02-08T13:53:57.072,"{'LEFT'}"
2021-02-08T13:53:57.076,"{'LEFT'}"
2021-02-08T13:53:57.080,"{'LEFT'}"
2021-02-08T13:53:57.084,"{'LEFT'}"
2021-02-08T13:53:57.088,"{'LEFT'}"
2021-02-08T13:53:57.092,"{'LEFT'}"
2021-02-08T13:53:57.096,"{'LEFT'}"
2021-02-08T13:53:57.100,"{'LEFT'}"
2021-02-08T13:53:57.105,"{'LEFT'}"
2021-02-08T13:53:57.109,"{'LEFT'}"
2021-02-08T13:53:57.113,"{'LEFT'}"
2021-02-08T13:53:57.118,"{'LEFT'}"
2021-02-08T13:53:57.122,"{'LEFT'}"
2021-02-08T13:53:57.126,"{'LEFT'}"
2021-02-08T13:53:57.130,"{'LEFT'}"
2021-02-08T13:53:57.134,"{'LEFT'}"
2021-02-08T13:53:57.138,"{'LEFT'}"
2021-02-08T13:53:57.142,"{'LEFT'}"
2021-02-08T13:53:57.146,"{'LEFT'}"
2021-02-08T13:53:57.153,"{'LEFT'}"
2021-02-08T13:53:57.156,"{'LEFT'}"
2021-02-08T13:53:57.160,"{'LEFT'}"
2021-02-08T13:53:57.165,"{'LEFT'}"
2021-02-08T13:53:57.170,"{'LEFT'}"
2021-02-08T13:53:57.174,"{'LEFT'}"
2021-02-08T13:53:57.179,"{'LEFT'}"
2021-02-08T13:53:57.182,"{'LEFT'}"
2021-02-08T13:53:57.187,"{'LEFT'}"
2021-02-08T13:53:57.192,"{'LEFT'}"
2021-02-08T13:53:57.196,"{'LEFT'}"
2021-02-08T13:53:57.200,"{'LEFT'}"
2021-02-08T13:53:57.205,"{'LEFT'}"
2021-02-08T13:53:57.209,"{'LEFT'}"
2021-02-08T13:53:57.213,"{'LEFT'}"
2021-02-08T13:53:57.217,"{'LEFT'}"
2021-02-08T13:53:57.223,"{'LEFT'}"
2021-02-08T13:53:57.226,"{'LEFT'}"
2021-02-08T13:53:57.230,"{'LEFT'}"
2021-02-08T13:53:57.235,"{'LEFT'}"
2021-02-08T13:53:57.239,"{'LEFT'}"
2021-02-08T13:53:57.243,"{}"
2021-02-08T13:53:57.255,"{}"
2021-02-08T13:53:57.255,"{}"
2021-02-08T13:53:57.263,"{}"
2021-02-08T13:53:57.264,"{}"
```

нужно узнать разницу во времени между первым не пустым и последним значением mouse_key и нужно это выполнить максимально быстро

Comment: "между первым не пустым и последним значением" это что значит?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вряд ли средствами python вам удастся существенно ускорить само чтение файла. но вот оптимизировать код можно как-то так:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("mouse.csv")
df["time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["time"])
print((df.iloc[-1, 0] - df.iloc[0, 0]))
```

получим:

```
0 days 00:00:00.251000
```

либо можете просто результат перевести в секунды:

```
print((df.iloc[-1, 0] - df.iloc[0, 0]).total_seconds())
```

> 0.251

Answer (score 0):

Максимально быстро это хорошо:) Интересно, это как?) В общем, я реализовал бы это как-то вот так:

```
import csv
from datetime import datetime

path = '_path_to_csv_file_'

with open(path)as f:
    content = csv.reader(f)
    for time, value in content:
        if value == "{'LEFT'}":
            non_empty = time #первое не пустое
            break
    for i in csv.reader(f):
        tmp_value = i[0]
    final_value = tmp_value

non_empty = non_empty.replace('T', '-')
final_value = final_value.replace('T', '-')

time_start = datetime.strptime(non_empty, "%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S.%f")
time_stop =  datetime.strptime(final_value, "%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S.%f")
print(f"{time_stop-time_start}")
```

Comment: а где здесь максимально быстро? если делать не "максимально быстро", с просто "делать", то уж лучше через pandas - количество кода раз в 5-7 уменьшится.